# AngularJs provider in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I had build a Angularjs provider in typescript wondering is there any better way of doing the same,my sample provider create an abstraction of console logger,the interface is just to keep the compiler happy , and I register the provider as in the code below

```
module ec{
    export interface ILoggerService{
    warn(message:string):void;
    info(message:string):void;
    error(message:string):void;
    debug(message:string):void;
    log(message:string,exception?:any):void;

   }
}

module ec.providers {

    export class loggerService {
      private loggerState:boolean = false;

    public start =() =>{
        this.loggerState = true;
    }

    public $get =['$log',($log:ng.ILogService) =>{
        return {
            warn:(message) =>{
                  if(this.loggerState)
                  $log.warn(message);
            },
            info:(message) =>{
                if(this.loggerState)
                    $log.info(message);
            },
            error:(message) =>{
                if(this.loggerState)
                    $log.error(message);
            },
            debug:(message) =>{
                if(this.loggerState)
                    $log.debug(message);
            },
            log:(message,exception) =>{
                if(this.loggerState)
                    $log.log(message,exception);
            }

        }
    }]

   }

}


module ec{

  var app =angular.module('foo',[]).config(['loggerServiceProvider',  (loggerServiceProvider)=>{
              if(location.hostname =='localhost') {
                      loggerProvider.start();
               }
      }]);
      app.provider(providers);
}
```

Comment: When is called the method `start`?

Comment: @Tarh added the start method use.

Answer (score 2):

## With a provider: The dynamic way

```
module MyNameSpace {
    export interface ILoggerService {
        warn(message: string): void;
        info(message: string): void;
        error(message: string): void;
        debug(message: string): void;
        log(message: string, exception?: any): void;
    }
    export function loggerService {
        var serv = new LoggerService();
        this.start = () => {
            // ...
        };
        this.$get = ['$log',($log: ng.ILogService) => {
            var methods = ['warn', 'info', 'error', 'debug', 'log'],
                obj: any = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; ++i)
                obj[methods[i]] = (msg: string) => $log[methods[i]](msg);
            return obj;
        }];

    }
}
```

## With a provider: Class

```
module MyNameSpace {
    export interface ILoggerService {
        warn(message: string): void;
        info(message: string): void;
        error(message: string): void;
        debug(message: string): void;
        log(message: string, exception?: any): void;
    }
    export function loggerService {
        var serv = new LoggerService();
        this.start = () => {
            // ...
        };
        this.$get = ['$log',($log:ng.ILogService) => {
            serv.start($log);
            return serv;
        }];

    }
    class LoggerService implements ILoggerService {
        private $log: ng.ILogService;
        public start($log: ng.ILogService) {
            this.$log = $log;
        }
        public warn(message) {
            if(this.$log)
                this.$log.warn(message);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

## With a service

You can replace the `provider` with a `service`:

```
class LoggerService {
    private loggerState = false;
    static $inject = ['$log'];
    constructor(private $log: ng.ILogService) {
    }
    public start() {
        this.loggerState = true;
    }
    public warn(message) {
        if(this.loggerState)
            this.$log.warn(message);
    }
    // ...
}

app.service('LoggerService', LoggerService);
```

Comment: i need the provider to do some initial configuration